# Writing entries to the Windows Application Log c#

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a console app in which I need to write various entries to the Windows Application log.  As one would expect I was able to accomplish that with the following:

```
        EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();
        eventLog.Source = "Application";

        eventLog.WriteEntry("Sample application log entry", EventLogEntryType.Information, 1001, 0);
```

However the end result is:

---

*The description for Event ID xxxx from source Application cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.*

*If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.*

*The following information was included with the event: 
Sample application log entry*

*the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table*

---

Obviously a more professional look is appropriate here so how do I go about writing an entry that only contains the text I am wanting written to the log?

Comment: That's not how Event Log works. It's not a log file. You post *events* with data. The viewer loads that data, finds the appropriate message text and formats them. If the messages are missing, the viewer can't create a format and displays this error message. Posting a full text message defeats the purpose of a near-real-time event log system

Comment: So are you saying WriteEvent would be better than WriteEntry?

Comment: No, I'm saying that's not how Event Log works. Without the message DLL, you get that error message. If you use EventLog directly, you need that DLL that can only be created using C++ tools. You should use [ETW EventSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource(v=vs.110).aspx) instead,either directly or through the . This allows you to define events and messages in a single class but only emit an EventID and data. The runtime takes care of generating and registering the appropriate messages from the Event attribute

Comment: I see and will give ETW EventSource a shot.  Thanks

Comment: What you emit, and what Windows receives is just the Event ID and data. ETW then retrieves and formats the registered message